# Get element from single-value dictionary without knowing name

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have a dictionary as defined below:

```
interface dict {[key: string]: number}
```

I have an instance `myDict` of dict which I know contains a single element. How can I get its key and value without knowing the key name? I can think of this solution:

```
for(const key in myDict){
    console.log(key)
    console.log(myDict[key])
}
```

I wonder if there is a cleaner way that doesn't use a for loop.

Comment: You could try `Object.keys(myDict)[0]`, but remember that a for-in loop enumerates through the prototype chain and this might have an unintended effect.

Answer (score 1):

```
// object is probably a Record (aka Object dictionary)
function getTheOnlyPropertyValue<T extends Record<keyof any, any>>(
    object: T
// get values in object
): T[keyof T] {
    // get the whole list of property values in object as an array, builtin
    let values = Object.values(object)
    // also see Object.keys, Object.entries

    // you probably don't need this, but it ensures correctness
    if (values.length !== 1) throw new Error('must have 1 value');
    return values[0];
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your code?